# signIn(user) not working in quickblox android project

Tags: quickblox

I m building an android simple chat project using Quickblox sdk2.5.1 but everytime i click on Login Button, getting error.what wrong in that code? plz help[this is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jnijq.png)

Comment: What error do you get and can you post some code to show how you are trying to implement it?

Comment: @Norris Boateng i have attach my code as image. Plz take a look.

Comment: the code seems alright. What error are you getting?

Comment: I have solve the problem.

Comment: Great. Add it as an answer for someone who might go through the same issue.

Comment: @Devb please post your solution as an answer, so everybody will see it